# Choosing substrings of at least length $k$ from a string of length $l$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For a string of length $l$, the number of ways to choose substrings of at least length $k$ is $$\binom{l - k + 2}{l - k}$$

My work:

The total number of substrings in a string of length $l$ is:
$\frac{l(l + 1)}{2}$

To calculate the number of substrings of length less than $k$, we need to consider substrings of lengths $1, 2, 3, ..., k-1$. The number of such substrings is: $\frac{(k - 1)k}{2}$

Therefore, the number of substrings of length at least $k$ in a string of length $n$ is:

Total substrings $-$ Substrings of length less than $k$ is:
$ \frac{l(l + 1)}{2} - \frac{(k - 1)k}{2} = \frac{(l(l + 1) - (k - 1)k)}{2}$

How do I proceed forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$\binom{l - k + 2}{l - k} = \frac{(l - k + 2)!}{(l - k)!2!} = \frac{(l - k + 2)(l - k + 1)}{2}$$
counts the number of nonempty substrings of length at least $k$ in a string of length $l$.

Your count for the number of nonempty substrings of length less than $k$ is incorrect.  You counted the number of nonempty substrings of length less than $k$ in a string of length $k - 1$ rather than a string of length $l$.

Since a nomempty substring of length $j$ cannot begin in the last $j - 1$ positions of a string of length $l$, there are $l - (j - 1) = l + 1 - j$ nonempty substrings of length $j$ in a string of length $l$.  Hence, the number of nonempty substrings in a string of length $l$ is
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{l} (l + 1 - j) = \sum_{i = 1}^{l} i = \frac{l(l + 1)}{2}$$

The number of nonempty substrings of length less than $k$ in a string of length $l$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} (l + 1 - j) & = (l + 1)\sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} j\\
& = (l + 1)(k - 1) - \frac{k(k - 1)}{2}\\
& = \frac{2(l + 1)(k - 1) - k(k - 1)}{2}\\
& = \frac{2(lk - l + k - 1) - k^2 + k}{2}\\
& = \frac{2lk - 2l + 2k - 2 - k^2 + k}{2}\\
& = \frac{2lk - 2l + 3k - k^2 - 2}{2}
\end{align*}
Thus, the number of nonempty substrings of length at least $k$ in a string of length $l$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{l(l + 1)}{2} - \frac{2lk - 2l + 3k - k^2 - 2}{2} & = \frac{l^2 + l - 2lk + 2l - 3k + k^2 + 2}{2}\\
& = \frac{l^2 - 2lk + k^2 + 3l - 3k + 2}{2}\\
& = \frac{(l - k)^2 + 3(l - k) + 2}{2}\\
& = \frac{(l - k + 2)(l - k + 1)}{2}\\
& = \binom{l - k + 2}{l - k}
\end{align*}

**An alternate approach**

Suppose our string is $1, 2, 3, \ldots, l$.  We wish to count how many nonempty substrings of length at least $k$ there are.

Suppose we have $l$ blue balls and $2$ dividers.  Set aside $k \geq 1$ of the $l$ balls, leaving $l - k$ blue balls and $2$ dividers to arrange in a row.  There are $l - k + 2$ positions to fill with the remaining $l - k$ blue balls and the $2$ dividers.  We can fill $l - k$ of them with blue balls in
$$\binom{l - k + 2}{l - k}$$
ways, placing the two dividers in the remaining two positions.  Next place the remaining $k$ balls to the immediate right of the first divider.  Then there will be at least $k$ balls between the two dividers.  Paint the balls between the two dividers green.  Number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the numbers in the substring of at length at least $k$.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{l - k + 2}{l - k}$$
nonempty substrings of length at least $k$ in a string of length $l$.